# Как правильно? Перед перечислением слово в единственном числе или во множественном?

Tags: орфография

> В комплект учебных материалов входит: образцы документов, задачи и
> задания.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Подлежащее и сказуемое должны согласовываться в роде, числе, падеже (координироваться). Если у нас подлежащие во множественном числе, то и сказуемое ставим во множественное:

*В комплект учебных материалов входят: образцы документов, задачи и задания.*

Единственное число будет, если появится обобщающее слово: *В комплект учебных материалов входит следующее: образцы документов, задачи и задания.*

Если бы это не было технической документацией, то и двоеточия здесь не было бы: *В комплект учебных материалов входят образцы документов, задачи и задания.* Согласуются ближайшие слова (входят образцы документов).

Но это документация, деловой язык, поэтому ставим двоеточие, которое предупреждает читателя, что дальше следует перечисление, функцию обобщающего слова здесь выполняет сказуемое. В справочнике Розенталя:

> Если однородным членам предложения не предшествует обобщающее слово
> (словосочетание), то перед ними двоеточие ставится только в том
> случае, когда необходимо предупредить читателя, что дальше следует
> перечисление: Из-под сена виднелись: самовар, кадка с мороженной
> формой и ещё какие-то привлекательные узелки и коробочки (Л. Т.). Ср.
> в деловой и научной речи: На заседании присутствовали:…; Для получения
> смеси нужно взять:…; Роли исполняют:…; В ролях: …

А **в препозиции** сказуемое согласуется **во множественном числе** с однородными членами (и обобщающим словом, если оно имеется).